# What does assign do in rspec-rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, unit-testing, rspec, rspec-rails

I am working on code that I haven't written and trying to understand how RSpec works.

```
let(:course) { create :new_course }
before { assign :course, course }
```

I know that `let` creates a memoized variable.
What does `assign` do in this example?

Comment: Not to be confused with `assigns` which is a hash that contains template instance variables. For example, you may use `assign` in the test setup step, and `assigns` in the test verification step.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You must be looking at a view spec. In an rspec-rails view spec, `assign` assigns its second argument to the template instance variable named by the first argument. In your example, `assign :course, course` sets `@course` in the template to the value of `course`.

More here: https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-rails/v/3-3/docs/view-specs/view-spec